# Can I access device commands in Lenze 9400 Highline servo drive with twincat3 via CoE?

Tags: drive, servo, twincat, canopen

I want to access and change parameters on a Lenze 9400 Highline drive, specifically the device commands. I know i can do it via the CANOpenOverEthercat with Twincat3 but i don't know exactly how. I already have the drive as a device in my Twincat project.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with the Tc3_EtherCAT lib from beckhoff. You can find FBs there to read/write SDOs. First the ID and subID needs to be obtained of the desired parameter than is supposed to be read/written and put as an input in the fb: FB_EcCoeSdoReadEx or FB_EcCoeSdoWriteEx. Also, beckhoff has a sample prg for this at the following link: https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/ethercatsystem/4358261771.html&id=7226910604449245485
In my particular case, the ID of the parameter 'Device command' with codename 2 is: 5FFD with no subID. I'm still in the process of writing the program and actually executing it with the servo, but this is the way to do it.